# Changing class of object in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to give an object in the interface builder a custom class. When typing in the class name in the Identity Inspector it automatically finishes the line as its already present in the dropdown list of available classes. 
However after entering the class the page comes up with a padlock image and clears the class name.

What is the cause of this and how can I rectify it?

Comment: Did you tried with UIView ?

Comment: The custom class you are attempting to replace with must be a subclass of the item being replaced.

Comment: The file is a subclass of UITableViewCell

Comment: @Imran And are you trying to set this subclass for the dynamic cell prototype? If you delete the custom class field, do you see `UITableViewCell` there, or something else? Perhaps some screen snapshots (shift+command+4) before and after would help us visualize what's going on.

Comment: @Rob Yes if I delete the custom class, only `UITableViewCell` appears

Answer (score 3):

firstly, you must reload xcode

if it not work you must have subclass associate with it in IB

Create CustomClass:UITableViewCell then drop UITableViewCell to IB and then just type the name
If dropdown list not display, reload Xcode

Comment: There a custom class defined in the .h file as `@interface SimpleTableCell : UITableViewCell` Is this not correct? Also how should I reload XCode? Simply restarting the app or is there another way?

Comment: are you sure drag and drop exactly UITableViewCell to IB and click on it before type class name to Identity Inspector?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've specific the right IB object (e.g., a dynamic cell prototype, whose default class is `UITableViewCell`) and your custom class is defined correctly (as a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, itself), then I have a couple of thoughts of what you might try:

- Sometimes exiting and restarting Xcode is often enough.
- Also try selecting "Clean" from the "Build" menu (or press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).
- In the worst case scenario, sometimes you have to exit Xcode and delete the DerivedData folder and then restart Xcode. To find the derived data folder, press <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (comma) and go to the last tab, "Locations", and click on the arrow next to the "Derived Data" folder:

  [image]

  Having pulled up that folder in Finder, quit Xcode, delete the contents of that `DerivedData` folder in Finder (*after* quitting Xcode), and then restart Xcode and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution (not sure if I have found a fix for the actual problem or just found a way around it)...

I changed the Lock dropdown setting to `Nothing` and it now allows me to set my own custom class to the Object in the file. 
Whats strange is that the document lock was previously set to `Inherit (Nothing)` anyway so not sure what the difference is here.

[image]